# Reading lines from file and assigning into variables using ksh

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

I have a text file which looks like this:

```
John
25
Football
```

I have to read this file using shell script and I will be having 3 variables as name, age and passion in my script. I have to read the above text file and have to set `name` as "John", `age` as "25" and `passion` as "football" in my script.

Comment: I m using ksh scripting language

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please refer to [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question on this site, and thus get good answers. Being more precise about your issue, showing what is your code so far, and the errors you are facing, as well as what you have tried so far to solve the matter.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I applied code formats and highlighting to your question so the situation and wanted result can be better understood.

Comment: Thanks for your support m.raynal and sacchaM78. since i am new to unix scripting i don't know how and where to start

Comment: After researching in Google i m doing this code. while IFS= read -r NAME AGE PASSION
do
  echo "$NAME $AGE $PASSION"

done <"$FILEINPUT"

echo $NAME
echo $AGE
echo $PASSION. The echo statement not working and i dont have values in NAME,AGE and PASSION variables. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: When `${FILEINPUT}` is the correct name of your file, try `echo "name=$NAME"` in your loop. I think it will appear 3 times with different values.